# Why can't I see the list of .dem files in my /demo directory on Apache2 server?

Tags: apache2, apache2.4

I'm trying to link all .dem files inside /demo

```
Alias /demo /home/reyz/server/cstrike
<Directory "/home/reyz/server/cstrike">
    Options Indexes
    <FilesMatch "\.dem$">
        Require all granted
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

I put this into `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

i can access /demo/x.dem but can't see list of .dem files in /demo
[The error I get when I go to /demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCF61.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since you added an Alias that wasn't part of any existing DocumentRoot or similar, it's likely Apache is denying the access.  Normally you'd add a `Require all granted` in the Directory section but it looks like your intent is to not serve the rest of the files.

There is a workaround:

Inside your directory section:

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
Require expr "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#/$#"
```

Comment: Now it shows every file and folder in /home/reyz/server/cstrike and only have access to .dem files, can't view other files but can browse subfolders

i only wan't to show .dem files in /demo page

Comment: Maybe indexoptions -showforbidden? This is the default though, usually the faq is how to show them despite forbidden .